# How to bind height of panel to viewport height in Ext Js?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.5

I'm interested in automatically setting the height of a panel to the height of the viewport in Ext js.

Using listeners this is easy to do, but it seems to be a perfect use of Ext js variable binding. I can't seem to get it to work, however.

In my main view my bind config is,  `bind: {height: 'viewportHeight'}`. In the view model, I have `data: { viewportHeight: Ext.getViewportHeight()}`. I extend this view model with the view model for my panel class, and have `bind: {height: 'viewportHeight'}` in the view.

I thought this was how bindings work in Ext js, but viewportHeight is set at the initial viewport height, and then never updated. Resizing the window does not resize the panel.

What am I missing with variable binding in Ext js?

Comment: Is that actually how you're doing the binding?  If so, binding requires curly braces around the variable... otherwise, you're just binding to a string.  So it should be `bind: {height: '{viewportHeight}'}`  If that's just a typo in the description, would you mind giving us a Fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: I did have braces in the string. I'll link a fiddle when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use binding. ExtJs has layouts for these purposes:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    //layout: 'fit',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: "Sample Panel",
        html: "Content HTML",
        width: 200,
        margin: 5
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: "Another Panel",
        html: "Content HTML",
        width: 400,
        margin: 5
    }]
});
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. My viewport is a tabpanel with a gridpanel as a tab. The grid panel expands to the height of its rows, which is larger than the screen. I need the card layout for the tabpanel. Grid is set with scroll.

Comment: Hm, ok, then it would be nice to have a reproducible sample of your layout in the fiddle: dle.sencha.com